# Java: Why does my HashSet and TreeSet contain duplicates?

Tags: java, unique, hashset, treeset

When my text file contains this:

```
a b c b
```

My HashSet and TreeSet say there are 3 unique words.

When my text file contains this:

```
a b c a
```

My HashSet and TreeSet say there are 4 unique words.

Why?

```
  public static int countUnique1A(WordStream words) {

    HashSet<String> hashSetA = new HashSet<String>();
    for (String i : words) {
      hashSetA.add(i);
    }

    return hashSetA.size();
  }

  public static int countUnique1B(WordStream words) {

    TreeSet<String> treeSetA = new TreeSet<String>();
    for (String i : words) {
      treeSetA.add(i);
    }
    return treeSetA.size();
  }
```

Comment: What is in the `treeSetA` and `hashSetA` before you call `size()`? How do you construct `WordStream` & what is `WordStream`?

Comment: It doesn't contain duplicates. It *can't*. The strings aren't the same. Try printing out everything in the set, and you'll see. If you wrap your output in brackets it'll clearly show where your strings start and end, e.g. `System.out.println(String.format("[%s]", word));`

Comment: The bug is in `WordStream`, not the code you show here. Remove this code, and re-focus your question on `WordStream`.

Answer (score 6):

I guess it may be due to spaces between the words. E.g. `HashSet` may contain 'a' and 'a '. Can you try changing:

```
hashSetA.add(i);
```

to

```
hashSetA.add(i.trim());
```

We need to do the same for `treeSetA` as well.